# will ABS formula columns sort and match

Tags: excel

I am retired so I have a lot of free time on my hands so I like playing the greyhounds. Using Excel I attempted to help myself save time by sorting out two columns at a time (Post - B-SPD) etc, because you have to sort some low and some high. The columns not marked Post are formula columns =abs(a3) etc. but when I try to sort the Post columns will sort, but the column I try to sort with it does not sort and match the post number it is assigned to.

Can this be done or does the =ABS formula prevent it. Plus even using =ABS some of the number are negative but the -minus sign does not appear. I have tried everything using numbers, using currency, using general, but nothing works. One person sent me to control panel to the Clock, Language, and Region settings. go additional setting and set your negative setting there. But that would not let the -minus sign show up on negative numbers either.

Is any of the above even possible?

```
POST B-SPD  POST A-SPD  POST  8TH    POST L-SPD POST A-FIN
1   31.43   1   31.84   1     0      1    3     1    5.83
2   31.43   2   31.67   2    35.14   2    0     2    4.67
3   31.79   3   31.9    3    59.11   3    6     3    5.67
4   31.32   4   31.73   4    65.5    4    3     4    3.83
5   31.47   5   31.68   5    29.71   5    4     5    3.33
6   31.76   6   32.18   6   100      6    9     6    5.01
7   31.48   7   31.99   7    41.13   7    1     7    5.67
8   31.69   8   31.99   8    75.79   8    6     8    4.83
    LOW         LOW          HIGH         HIGH       LOW
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you will get a lot more help if you can edit your question to be a bit more clear. It's hard to understand fully what you are looking for, but it sounds very doable, in general. If you can edit your question with some clarity I am sure we can help :)

Comment: I second Scott's comment. Fairly hard to understand the exact question as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not clear but use of ABS should not cause sorting issues. =ABS (for absolute) function is to strip out minus signs (so seems to be working properly).

OP may be advised to delete all but one of the POST columns, select headers and data (not including 'LOW' or 'HIGH') and Insert > Tables - Table, check My table has headers, OK, then use the filter buttons to choose whether to Sort Smallest to Largest or Sort Largest to Smallest for whichever attribute is to be ordered (the other columns will 'follow suit'). The filter button will show which button is determining the ordering and whether ascending or descending (eg table below is sorted descending on '8TH'):

[image: SO13036896 example]